# Cancel events from a legacy form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a main form that has buttons, the role of one of them in disabling all controls of the form in general.

I also have a child form that inherits the buttons and the actions of them, as I could prevent the events of the parent form at a certain point from running that is, temporarily remove the event, for example if the user has a text and does not fill it out and gives the button I do not want anything to be disabled

I think there is a way in c# that like the "eventname"=- I don't remember well

**This is an example of my base or parent form, with a button that does actions**

[Parent Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MryMl.png)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class BaseMantenimiento1 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public BaseMantenimiento1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BaseMantenimiento1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Guardar.Enabled = false;
            Cancelar.Enabled = false;
            controles.habilitarcontroles(false, xtraTabControl1);
        }

        private void Nuevo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Guardar.Enabled = true;
            Cancelar.Enabled = true;
            Editar.Enabled = false;
            Buscar.Enabled = false;
            Nuevo.Enabled = false;

            controles.habilitarcontroles(true, xtraTabControl1);
            

        }
```

**This is my child form with its basic code**

[child form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9mlP.png)

```
 public partial class Mantenimiento_Empresas : BaseMantenimiento1
    {
        public Mantenimiento_Empresas()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

What I wanted was that if in the child form I gave the button save, but they did not fill the textbox well, then the event that this inherits from its parent form is not executed, so I took the event and then below if everything is fine I trigger the event of the parent with

```
base.Save_Click(null, null);
```

Comment: OK.  In the future I would suggest you [tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) your question with the framework(s) you are using as well as the language.  Doing so will increase your chances of getting the attention of someone who can answer.

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing your setup. When you say "child form," are you referring to an [MDI child](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-mdi-child-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), an [inheritance child](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance), or something else? Please clarify. A code example would help.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the event handler? Why do you not disable the button?

Comment: @JohnWu,  Hello, I mean an inheritance child , I will edit the question to give you examples with code, but I already found what I was looking for

Comment: @RezaAghaei Remove  the event handler, how the answer that from below to the forum

Comment: @RezaAghaei Of course I already did, but to help others leave examples above

Answer (score -1):

I found what I was looking for, in the same space where the components are initialized I must place the following

```
public Mantenimineto_Bicicletas()
{
    InitializeComponent();
   Save.Click -= base.Save_Click;
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this. This is a hack when you have two better options - either remove the handler from the designer code or override the `OnClick` method and chose when to actually raise the event.

Comment: @Enigmativity Great sounds better, Thanks for the idea.